# Parsec: intuit type from parsed string

Tags: haskell, generics, polymorphism, parsec

Is it possible to infer the type from `many1`?

## MWE

```
module Main where

import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Data.Either (rights)

type Vertex vertexWeight = (String, vertexWeight)

parseVertex :: Parser (Vertex a)
parseVertex = do
  name <- many1 (noneOf "/")
  char '/'
  weight <- many1 (noneOf "\n")
  return $ (name, weight)

main :: IO ()
main = do
     putStrLn $ rights $ [parse parseVertex "test" "a/2"]
```

In the above example, I'd like for the `weight` parameter to get outputted as an Int, but this does not type-check.

Would it be wiser to represent a vertex as `(String, String)` and define parsers for the weight?

Comment: `many1 (noneOf "\n") :: Parser String`. You can convert this to an Int in many ways - for example `read <$> many1 (noneOf "\n") :: Parser Int` - but note that the string parsed by `many1 (noneOf "\n")` might not be a number at all. There is a [package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-numbers-0.1.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-Number.html) which provides numeric parsers for Parsec, but if you want to roll your own you'll have to do something like `read <$> many1 (oneOf ['0'..'9']) :: Parser Int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `Parser (Vertex a)` is shorthand for `forall a. Parser (Vertex a)`, i.e. its type states that for *any* choice of `a`, it can have type `Parser (Vertex a)`. This is clearly not what you want: you want to say that `parseVertex` will always have type `Parser (Vertex a)` for *some* choice of `a`, but this choice is to be made by `parseVertex`, not at its call site.

What you should do, is use a type `T` such that `Parser (Vertex T)` covers all possible return values of `parseVertex`. For example, if you use `Parser (Vertex (Either Int String))`, then `parseVertex` can choose based on the parse results so far if it will return something of the form `(s, Left x)`, or `(s, Right t)`, where `s :: String`, `x :: Int` and `t :: String`.

Of course, that also means that consumers of `parseVector` now have to be able to handle both cases.